# Pandas: Right way to query timeseries with DateTime object

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, type-conversion

Let' take the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'Branch' : 'A A A A A B'.split(),
 'Date' : [
 pd.Timestamp('2009-04-05 01:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
 pd.Timestamp('2009-02-05 00:21:01+0000', tz='UTC'),
 pd.Timestamp('2010-05-05 07:52:20+0000', tz='UTC'),
 pd.Timestamp('2009-08-05 05:33:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
 pd.Timestamp('2011-02-05 02:09:33+0000', tz='UTC'),
 pd.Timestamp('2008-01-05 02:43:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
 ]})

 df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

and the following varialbe:

```
test_1 = dateutil.parser.parse('2010-05-05T07:52:20Z')
```

Is there any possibility to get the record of the DataFrame which matches the test date? and does anybody know why the following does not work?

I have already tried

```
df.ix[test_1]
```

but this throws an exception.

Moreover, I tried tp use the same type by doing:

```
test_2 = pd.Timestamp(test_1)
df.ix[test_2]
```

but this throws an exception, too.

Both times the expection is:

```
KeyError: 1357045200000000000
```

I deeply appreciate any help.

Andy

### Solution

I was working with an unoffical release of Pandas (in particular '0.13.1-223-g7cd9496') probably the issue is limited to this version. After using the official 0.13.1 release my code worked flawlessly.

Thanks to all

Comment: Can't reproduce in `pandas 0.13.1`, which version are you using and what are the exception messages?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I posted the error. I use pandas: '0.13.1-223-g7cd9496'

Answer (score 2):

I can get it on this way:

```
>test_1 = dateutil.parser.parse('2010-05-05T07:52:20Z')
>df['Branch'][test_1]
>'A'
```

Testing with :

```
>df.ix[test_1]
Branch    A
Name: 2010-05-05 07:52:20+00:00, dtype: object
```

works for me too...

Using:
python 2.7.5-5
python-pandas 0.12.0-2

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this more of a workaround? Do you think it is a bug? why is it not working in the first place?

Comment: Can you please post your pd.__version__ I have an idea